# Are gear list review questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

It is common for backpackers to request feedback on their gear list. However, questions of this type are sometimes closed.

- https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5322/hiking-camping-mount-marcy

This gear review exercise can serve beyond the person who asked the question. Others who may plan similar activities may benefit from the documented knowledge. The information gathered from community experts is often invaluable for trip planning.

Should gear list reviews be accepted on TGO?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might depend on how generalized the gear review question is. If it is something like

> I plan to pack the following things:

- a hardshell jacket and trousers
- five pieces of sports underwear (two long sleeves, three t-shirts)
- a 2 person tent
- a down sleeping bag with -5° C rating
- food for three days

> do you think this is appropriate or would you recommend something else/more/different?

Then I would say this is a question that will help others as well. But if it is something like

> I plan to pack the following things:

- my "super cool brand" jacket and "other fancy brand" trousers
- two "brand xy – bla" shirts and three "brand z - bla" t-shirts
- ...

where the list is a more or less complete dump of specifically named gear, this might be of little use for other people. So the first example would be OK for me, the second wouldn't. In former times (about a year ago) there was still a closing reason for that called "too localized".

But I see another possible issue here: I see the danger of getting one question for every more or less popular destination (mountain, long distance trail etc.) and then for different times of the year, such as

- I plan to hike XY trail in late summer...
- I want to climb mountain Z in winter...

To answer the question if gear list reviews should be accepted, I am somewhere between neutral and "do not accept". I.e. I would say by default not, but if it is formulated broad enough so that it's not entirely focused on special brand gear and might be also generalized to similar destinations I would give it a go.